# How to make login page in iphone using webservices

Tags: iphone, json

I'm working on an app that asks the user to login to access some of his informations. I have a login.jsp file that is store on the server and all the usernames and passwords on the database.

On my app i have 2 uitextfields one for the username and one for the password. I understand that i can use the POST method to pass on the input to the web server and check whether the username and password match to then load the rest of the data. This is where am having trouble, can anyone help me with it, how do i pass on the inputs from the uitextfield to that web service to run the login.jsp script?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSON is a format for exchanging information with a server. And a "login page" is obviously a UI for collecting information from a user (such as a user id and password), and possibly authenticating with a server, with whom you're using JSON format for the requests and responses to send and receive. It's impossible to answer this question in the abstract. You need to tell us what server you're trying to "log in" to (if that's what you're even trying to do) and the particulars of the interface that server provides. That will dictate what your implementation will look like.

Comment: Mr.@Rob i am improved the question.plz give me idea

Comment: Excellent: Much improved. Still, we probably need a few more details about the particulars of the interface for your JSP. For example, is it a HTTP POST? If you search StackOverflow for "[ios] http post", you'll probably see lots of good examples. I'd encourage you to search StackOverflow for similar answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// JDURLConnection.h

```
typedef void (^successBlock)(NSDictionary *dict);
typedef void (^errorBlock)(NSString *error);


@interface JDURLConnection : NSObject


+(void) urlRequestWithURL:(NSString *)urlStr
              usingMethod:(NSString *)verb
            andParameters:(NSDictionary *) param
          completionBlock:(successBlock)completed
               errorBlock:(errorBlock)errored;
@end
```

// JDURLConnection.m

```
+ (void) showMessageString:(NSString *)message{

    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"App Name!" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

}

#pragma mark - RequestMethods

+ (NSMutableURLRequest *) URLRequestFrom:(NSURL *)url verb:(NSString *)verb parameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters{


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
                                                       timeoutInterval:30];

    [request setHTTPMethod:verb];

    if (parameters != nil) {


        NSData *jsonData = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@",[parameters JSONRepresentation]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    }

    return request;
}



+(void) urlRequestWithURL:(NSString *)urlStr usingMethod:(NSString *)verb andParameters:(NSDictionary *) param completionBlock:(successBlock)completed errorBlock:(errorBlock)errored{

  //  [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeClear];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self URLRequestFrom:url verb:verb parameters:param];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

      //  [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil){

            id responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

            NSLog(@"%@",responseData);

            NSDictionary *responseDict = nil;

            if ([responseData isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                responseDict = (NSDictionary *)responseData;

            else if ([responseData isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
                responseDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:responseData forKey:@"result"];

            else
                responseDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"" forKey:@"error"];

            completed(responseDict);

        }
        else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showMessageString:) withObject:@"Error! unable to receive the data from Server." waitUntilDone:YES];

            errored(@"Error! unable to receive the data from Server.");

        }
        else if (error != nil){

            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showMessageString:) withObject:[error localizedDescription] waitUntilDone:YES];

            errored([error localizedDescription]);

        }
    }];

}
```

Implement this as:

```
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username",@"password", nil];
    NSArray *values =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.tfUserName.text,self.tfUserPass.text,nil];

    NSDictionary *param = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

    [JDURLConnection urlRequestWithURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://yourwebURL/API/user-login"] usingMethod:@"POST" andParameters:param completionBlock:^(NSDictionary *dict)
     {

         if ([dict objectForKey:@"result"]) {

                 NSLog(@"%@",dict);
         }

     }
         errorBlock:^(NSString *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",error);
//         errored(error);
     }];
```